# httpURLConnection.getInputStream() - 403 response - android

Tags: php, android, mysql, httpurlconnection

I am learning android. What i am trying to achieve here is a simple connection between server and android device.

I am using WAMP and have installed it. When i try hitting the php page (server script to retrieve from db) via browser (using postman) i am able to achieve what i want.

I configured my own network ip for the url below and it worked just fine in wamp and it did work in postman as well. I am using a real android device and it is in the same connection as that of my system (wifi)

My code: I have two activities and corresponding xmls

1. MainActivity ( is my Login page)
2. register
3. Welcome (On successful login)

I have a class for named BackgroundTask to perform the transaction

**BackgroundTask** class:

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
  Context ctx;

    BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String reg_url = "http://<my ip here>/<myproject>/register.php";
        String login_url = "http://<my ip here>/<myproject>/login.php";
        String method = params [0];
        if(method.equals("register"))
        {
            String firname = params[1];
            String lasname = params[2];
            String ages = params[3];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("firstname","UTF-8")+ "="+URLEncoder.encode(firname,"UTF-8")+ "&" +
                              URLEncoder.encode("lastname","UTF-8")+ "="+URLEncoder.encode(lasname,"UTF-8")+ "&" +
                              URLEncoder.encode("age","UTF-8")+ "="+URLEncoder.encode(ages,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();

         int responsecode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                if (responsecode >= 400 && responsecode <= 499) {
                throw new Exception("Bad authentication status: " + responsecode); //provide a more meaningful exception message
                 }
                else {
                //Get response from the server
                    InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    IS.close();
                 }
                return  "Registration Successful";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

**Register** activity:

```
public class register extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText fname, lname, age;
    Button send;
    String Firstname,Lastname,Age;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        initializevars();
    }

    public void initializevars() {
        fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirstName);
        lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLastName);
        age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    }

    public void userReg(View view)
    {
        Firstname = fname.getText().toString();
        Lastname = lname.getText().toString();
        Age = age.getText().toString();

        String method = "register";
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(method,Firstname,Lastname, Age);
        finish();

    }

}
```

**Error message**:

> Bad Authentic status : 403 in this part of the code
>
> int responsecode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
>   if (responsecode >= 400 && responsecode <= 499) {
>       throw new Exception("Bad authentication status: " + responsecode); //provide a more meaningful exception message
>   }
>   else {
>      //Get response from the server
>      InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
>      IS.close();
>   }

What I tried so far:

I looked at few stackoverflow answers but was unable to figure out the issue. i tried using

> getErrorstream

I did not get the error message, but my data did not reach the database.

Please let me know if my server scripts are required for additional info and i will add them as well

Requesting your guidance and support.

Thanks

***EDIT***

my php scripts

**init.php**

```
<?php

$db_name = "dbname";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = "<mypassword here>";
$server_name = "localhost";

$con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);

if(!$con)

    {
        //echo "Connection Error".mysqli_connect_error();
    }else
    {
        //echo "<h3> Connection Success  </h3>";
    }

?>
```

**register.php**

```
<?php

    require "init.php";

    $first_name = $_POST["firstname"];
    $last_name = $_POST["lastname"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];

    $sql_query = "insert into details values ('$first_name','$last_name','$age');";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))
    {
        //echo "<h3> data insertion successful </h3>";
    } else
        {
            //echo "Error".mysqli_error($con);
        }

    ?>
```

Screenshot of POSTMAN & DB

[image: POSTMAN IMAGE]

[image: DB UPdate]

W**hen i replace the localhost with my ip, it works as well**. In the db pic, u can see 2 records. my bad. I hit 'Send' button twice in postman

**EDIT 2 -**

I tried using the android emulator rather  than physical device. CHanged the ip to emulator's ip (10.0.x.x)  It worked like a charm. I was able to see the records in db as well.

As suggested by @cricket_007 i feel its ip issue. Any help on that front would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Can you try doing this using a plugin on your browser (client for making http requests)?

Comment: Tip: your response code check is too broad and your custom message isn't helpful... A 404 is not bad authentication... Anyways a 403 error means Forbidden, so it does sound like a problem with the server

Comment: @Eenvincible : I tried using postman and http post request to it. I was able to get response perfectly. Should i check something additionally. Please let me know

Comment: @cricket_007 : Can you please put me on the right track on this. I am using Wamp and i added my port as weill to firewall. when i tried it with my network ip, i was able to see wamp homescreen and i check this with postman and i was able to successfully insert data in my db as well

Comment: Your data is getting to the server, so it's not a firewall problem. Whatever your PHP is doing to check those parameters it is sent, it is returning a forbidden error code

Comment: Additionally, do you have your PHP to accept form encoded data in a POST method or url parameters with a GET? like `http://url?firstName=test&lastName=test&age=30`?

Comment: @cricket_007 : Sorry for being naive, but i am trying understand few concepts here. I have added my php scripts as well. I am trying to achieve a connection to my android device.

Comment: Can you share a screeenshot of a working Postman request, as well?

Comment: @cricket_007 : I have added the screenshots now. Thanks. Please let me know for more infromation

Comment: From my limited knowledge of php, I can't see anything wrong there, plus you say it works with Postman, so I guess the problem must be with how you are sending the POST data in Android, but I'm unsure how that would cause a 403. Are you sure the URL is correct?

Comment: @cricket_007 : Thanks much. Appreciate it :). Yes, i have replaced local host with my ip as well. and both the android device and system are on the same network. i tried my ip with port in postman. It worked as well. i was able to see the entry in db

Comment: I suppose you could try some simpler http methods on the Android side and add the corresponding php code  (the volley or OkHttp libraries may help you there) and see if you can successfully make any requests. Also, I find JSON data easier to manage than url encoded  form data, so that's something to look into

Comment: @cricket_007 : Thank you so so much :) I will definitely look in to them as well. Just to Update. i tried using the emulator than android device. using 10.0.X.X in the URL ( ip for emulator) and bingo i was able to make it work and no error. Worked like a charm. I think you are right. it seems to be the ip address issue. Any suggestions/ help on that end.??

Comment: Just replace the 10.0.X.X with your actual local IP, be that 192.168.X.X, or whatever, and I don't see why that wouldn't work

Comment: @cricket_007 : No luck.That was my first try. Using 192.168.x.x and that's when i faced this issue. i thought of giving it a try with emulator and it seems to work .